# Can Poetry automatically choose a package version based on the version of the corresponding C library

Tags: python-poetry

I'll use GDAL as a specific example. In order to install the `gdal` Python package, you must have the GDAL C library installed first. You must also install a version of Python `gdal` to match the version of your installed C library.

```
$ gdal-config --version
3.2.0 <-- this is the version needed for Python gdal
```

I'm wondering whether there is any way to configure Poetry to install a version of `gdal` the matches the installed C library.

Comment: [Answered elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75141719/96588), but not a dupe since the other question was basically the inverse.