# Specifying version of GDAL dependency with Poetry

Tags: python-3.x, python-poetry, gdal-python-bindings

My Python project uses Poetry for dependency management. It requires the GDAL package, which (on Linux) requires that `libgdal-dev` is installed on the system. Moreover, the version of the Python package should match that of `libgdal-dev`.

How do I handle this situation with Poetry?

I could fix the version of the Python package in `pyproject.toml` and require users to install the same version of `libgdal-dev`. However, the available versions of `libgdal-dev` are very much constrained, depending on the system. For example, only one GDAL version per Ubuntu version is available on the standard [Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdal) and it varies depending on the Ubuntu version. Moreover, my project also needs to work on a Linux cluster which has a bunch of `libgdal-dev` versions installed, but no easy way of installing a different one.

Ideally, the GDAL version in `pyproject.toml` would be dynamic, and obtained e.g. from an environment variable but that doesn't seem to be supported.

### Edit

I just found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70424390/determine-version-of-package-to-install-via-bash-commands-output-in-poetry?rq=2), of which mine is essentially a duplicate. However, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75141719/6610407) basically does the reverse of what the OP (and I) asked for: setting the version of `libgdal-dev` to that specified in `pyproject.toml`. This may be sufficient for some scenarios, but not in mine, as question hopefully illustrates.

Comment: Not a full solution but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73631683/poetry-built-package-with-os-specific-dependencies